# View next image from the same folder using picturebox in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using an Openfiledialog to get the initial image and display it in a picturebox. Is there a way I could creating a button to display the next image that is in the same folder as the first one.  like the 'next' button in Windows Photo Viewer.

Comment: Define *next image*. Do you have a list of file names? If not, there is no *previous* or *next* image.

Comment: Try using a AJAX slideshow extender, they have all the features easily accesible